# Reverse accessor clashes in Django

Tags: python, django

Error :
1) user.Login.password: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Login.password' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Login.username'.
2) user.Login.username: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Login.username' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Login.password'.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class User(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
     position = models.CharField(max_length=50)

     def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('user:register', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Login(models.Model):
     username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     password = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
          login = {'username': self.username, 'password': self.password}
          return login
```

Comment: you don't need create an user model, django has one by default in `django.contrib.auth.models`

Comment: What is the reason for both password and usernaming having fk relation with User?

Comment: Even if this structure made sense, which it absolutely doesn't, you **must not** do this. Use Django's User model; if you need to create your own, inherit from AbstractBaseUser.

Answer (score 7):

You can solve the issue by using `related_name` attribute:

```
class Login(models.Model):
     username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="username_users")
     password = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="password_users")
```

But I am not getting the reason for you having both password and username having fk relation with User!!!

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind the clash, I mean field names are different, then where is the problem?